# css only ribbon and iOS

Tags: ios, css, ribbon

I've got some css only ribbons which work well / don't pixelate - but when I create one as a link, the ribbon elements, in iOS only, take on the link colour, rather than the stated colours.

Example here:
http://codepen.io/tincanben/full/YXjXdQ/

```
<a class="ribbon" href="">
  Left Ribbon Link Here
</a>
```

any ideas?

thanks in advance
ben